# GoogleTv Emulator Basic Text Entry

Tags: google-tv

I recently set up my googleTV emulator on Ubuntu 12 Desktop edition. Added Android SDK and the ADT plugin for Eclipse. When I start the emulator, I see the google Icon and some buttons as expected with 4 other icons on the TV screen. 
When I do select the TV option,I am propmted to enter the ZIPCode for LiveTV. Thats when I realised that I cant enter text using my keyboard!
My direction keys are working with the simulator for navigation but I just cant enter the ZIP code / Search Text .
Has anyone experienced the same issue ?

Comment: I ran the emulator with -debug-keys option. All the commands from the keyboard are recognised by the device. When entering text/numbers to the textbox (Eg. ZipCode / Search Text) , nothing happens. I am stuck up with this for sometime now. Any insights?

Comment: I have fixed this error Updating in Stack Overflow for other users. The AVD manager has a property 'Keyboard Support' which as per the documentation has a default value TRUE. But for me, It was set to false. Once I added the property and updated the AVD, it started working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/ and I will have someone look into it. AFAIK this was working correctly - can you provide some more detail on your system setup? SDK versions, any recent library updates etc.